# Can『ます形』やすい and 『ます形』にくい be rephrased as やすく『ます形』and にくく『ます形』?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following.

> 長い鉛筆は書きやすいです。
>
> 短い鉛筆は書きにくいです。

Can I rephrase them as follows?

> 長い鉛筆ではやすく書きます。
>
> 短い鉛筆ではにくく書きます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid your last two sentences make no sense, but at least you are clearly thinking "logically" here because those two sentences would surely work if they were in another language.

「やすい」(= "easy to do/handle") , in modern Japanese, is mainly used in the format:

> 「[連用形]{れんようけい} of a verb + やすい」

When in that format, one can conjugate 「やすい」 into 「やすく」 if one needs to add another phrase to it as in:

「このPCは使いやす**く**、しかも[安]{やす}い！」= "This PC is not only easy to use, but is also inexpensive!"

(Hope my use of 「やすい」 and 「安い」 in one sentence did not confuse some users.)

Your last two sentenes could be corrected to something like:

「[長]{なが}い[鉛筆]{えんぴつ}は(or なら)うまく[書]{か}けます。」 書**け**ます ＞ 書**き**ます

「[短]{みじか}い鉛筆ではうまく書けません。」

Comment: 1+ What do you think about the following?

長い鉛筆で使う時は書きやすくなります。

Comment: Better: 長い鉛筆を使うと書きやすくなります.